# Are the Tholians humanoid species?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos, star-trek-enterprise

In the TOS episode: “The Tholian Web”, the Tholian Loskene has only its head visible, and it looks as they are unlike any humanoid we've ever seen before. However, in the *Enterprise* episode: “In A Mirror, Darkly” they have legs and arms and are somewhat like other insectoid humanoids. So, my question is: are Tholians humanoid?

Comment: Downvoting for lack of research... https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Tholian

Comment: Benjamin Erickson, is there any reason why your question is not answered directly by the *Enterprise* episode you cite? Or are you trying to ask "what does *humanoid* mean?"

Comment: You need to define *humanoid* in a way that can be answered objectively. There is no strict definition of how much and in what ways a species needs to resemble a human to be called "humanoid," so without precise parameters it's an opinion-based question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No, [Tholians are not humanoid.](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Tholian?file=Tholian_pilot.jpg)**

Since the TOS episode you mentioned left the remainder of the Tholian's body open to interpretation, the Enterprise episode filled in that gap, canonically, by making them non-humanoid.